# VB Script Regex Remove digits after second decimal place

Tags: regex, vbscript

I've got programs I'm trying to clean up by simply truncating the number to 2 decimal places. I'm not worried about correct rounding. This will be a subroutine added into a larger "Cleanup" VB script I've been working on for the specific code inspection machines use. (DMIS code)

I've been using REGEX101 and gotten as far as find a number of ways to match the information I'm using. The one below captures all the information I need to keep from the line in a single group

```
^GOTO\/(\w+,\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+)
```

The lines I'm starting with look like this

```
GOTO/CART,0.0025,-2.0533,1
```

and I'm trying to get

```
GOTO/CART,0,-2.05,1
```

Trailing decimals (1.00) would be acceptable, but not preferred. ALso, the CART, needs to be kept unchageds, using a \w+ command (there are two possible word choices there) Is this something REGEX is capable of?

Comment: In VBS I'm not sure if it's possible, I'd create a function/method that takes a string, and returns a string. I'd break the long input string into a string array[] delimited by a comma and then take each element in the array, cast first element to string, and the rest to floats. Then round array element[1] and [3] to nearest whole or cast to int, and then element[2] use a rounding function to 2 decimal precisions. When it's all done do string addition + "," foreach element, and return it.

Comment: It's not important that 1.2399 converts to 1.23 ?

Comment: No, the commands are actually used to instruct physical moves on an inspection machine. Worst case scenario, I'm off on a move around a part by about twice the thickness of a piece of paper.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
>> s = "GOTO/CART,0.0025,-2.0533,1"
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Global = True
>> r.Pattern = "(\.\d{2})(\d+)"
>> WScript.Echo r.Replace(s, "$1")
>>
GOTO/CART,0.00,-2.05,1
>>
```

'remove(s) digits after second decimal place'.

Answer (score 1):

Without regex, rounding numbers:

```
mystr = "GOTO/CART,0.0025,-2.0533,1"
myarr = split(mystr,",")
outstr = myarr(0) & "," & round(myarr(1),2) & "," & round(myarr(2),2) & "," & round(myarr(3),2)
```

By Regex, remove digits after 2nd one, and removes `.00`:

```
(?=\.00)\.\d+|(?!\.00)(\.\d\d)\d+
//replace by $1
//"GOTO/CART,1.0025,-2.0533,1.0010" -> "GOTO/CART,1,-2.05,1"
```

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/c6ICjD/1)